# Font-Awesome Icon is displayed 3 times

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I have created a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/hima-chitalia/pen/NWbYyGr) where the font-awesome icon is displayed 3 times. I am not able to understand the reason for that. Any help or direction will be very useful.

```
<div>
  <navbar>
    <label>CZ</label>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="link" href="#"> Home </a></li>
      <li><a class="link" href="#"> About </a></li>
      <li><a class="link" href="#"> Blog </a></li>
      <li><a class="link" href="#"> Contact </a></li>
    </ul>
    <label id="icon">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"/>
    </lable>
    <input class="search"/> 
  </navbar>
  <div id="main"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `</lable>` should be `</label>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you can't close an `<i>` element like that, because `<i>` is not a void element.

```html
<i class="fa fa-bars"/>
```

You need to close it with a separate end tag:

```html
<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
```

Otherwise the browser doesn't think the `<i>` element is closed, so it interprets it like this:

```html
<label id="icon">
      <i class="fa fa-bars">
    
    <input class="search"> 
  </i></label></navbar><i class="fa fa-bars">
  <div id="main"></div>
</i>
```

Answer (score 1):

As D. Pardal said, you have to close your `<i>` by his close tag `</i>` Don't forget to correct the `</label>`. There is a little mistake.

```css
body {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0;
}
navbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: pink;
  color: white;
  line-height: 50px;
}

label{
  padding: 0 50px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  text-shadow: 2px 1px grey;
}

a {
  padding: 0 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white
}
ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

/* .link:hover{
  color: blue;
}

.link:visited{
  color: red;
} */

.search {
  margin-left: auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width;  5.9vw;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
  <navbar>
    <label>CZ</label>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="link" href="#"> Home </a></li>
      <li><a class="link" href="#"> About </a></li>
      <li><a class="link" href="#"> Blog </a></li>
      <li><a class="link" href="#"> Contact </a></li>
    </ul>
    <label id="icon">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </label>
    <input class="search"/> 
  </navbar>
  <div id="main"></div>
</div>
```